# Render an object's children from Firebase in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm following the "denormalized" data pattern that @Anant described nicely on the [Firebase blog](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). To query and render child objects he suggests listening for `child_added` events on the parent to get the child ids, then querying those children individually with `.once('value', fnc)` to render them. From the blog post (he uses a posted Link as the parent and Comments as children -- think Reddit or Hacker News):

```
var commentsRef =
  new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/comments");
var linkRef =
  new Firebase("https://awesome.firebaseio-demo.com/links");

var linkCommentsRef = linkRef.child(LINK_ID);
linkCommentsRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  commentsRef.child(snap.name()).once("value", function() {
  // Render the comment on the link page.
  ));
});
```

[*sic*]

I'm trying to reconcile this with my AngularJS view, since adding the result of `.once` into a `$scope` array and using `ngRepeat` will leave you with a static list (the children won't update in realtime if they are changed or removed by another client).

Put another way, I'd like to have something like an `angularFireCollection` of child objects that will add, remove and update dynamically.

Comment: Hmm. Besides the lack of automation, what's wrong with pushing the result of .once into an array, adding it to the $scope and using ngRepeat?

Comment: Yeah that works I had a bug when I tested it originally; I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a combination of [AngularFire](http://angularfire.com/) and [FirebaseIndex](https://github.com/Zenovations/FirebaseIndex). I haven't checked that combining these still works, but [Kato reports it has in the past](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-angular/53yA9NaHktw/3MEBT2u9hvEJ).

Ignoring that for a second, though, I don't see anything wrong with your proposed plan:

> push the result of `.once` into an array, add it to the `$scope` and use `ngRepeat`

In this case, Kato's FirebaseIndex will probably still be useful, so definitely check that out.

Comment: Good call on both points, I must have had a typo when I tried pushing a `.once` val into a `$scope` array earlier. So that works but obviously doesn't update in realtime. Kato's FirebaseIndex/AF solution looks great but is giving me an error, I submitted a post to the GG [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/53yA9NaHktw) you mentioned. Does it work for you?

Comment: @bennlich I have tested  AngularFire 0.3 and FirebaseIndex 0.0.4 and works fine. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok so it does work with `angularFireCollection` (great!) but I'm still getting an error when I try the FirebaseIndex as a ref for the implicit data binding (`angularFire`): `Error: I cannot process this event type: value`. Anyway, good enough for now, thanks @bennlich.